# Set variable to the returned value of a function, ran on that variable. c#

Tags: c#, function, variables

I was wondering if there is a way to shorten this code.

```
checkout.Find("Summary").GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text =checkout.Find("Summary").GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text.Replace("$V", InventoryManager.money.ToString());
```

As you can see, I have to run `checkout.Find("Summary").GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text` twice.
Once to set the variable, and once to run function `Replace()` on that variable.

Now at the top of my head I can think of a few ways to shorten this and make it more readable.
For example: setting a variable to the `Text` component, so I can more quickly (and less resource intensively) access it.

But I was wondering if there is a way to do something like this:

```
int someVar = 2;
someVar += 4;
```

But with the returned value of a function, so I can shorten the before mentioned code.

Any help would be appreciated.
(yes I am working in unity)

Comment: Store the result of `checkout.Find("Summary").GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>()` in a variable.  No need to repeat yourself.

Comment: Well that is Plan B, if this doesn't work.
Personally I don't like having a lot of variables.

Comment: @hoespilaar, why do you not like having lots of variables?  That's what they're there for.

Comment: To answer your question, no, you cannot use `+=` here because the original statement is an assignment replacing the original value, not appending to it.

Comment: I tend to be scared of performance being bad @Moo-Juice.

Comment: @hoespilaar It looks to me like evaluating `checkout.Find("Summary").GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>()` might be an expensive operation.  Which do you prefer more?  Not having variables and needing to repeat a (potentially) expensive operation, or having more efficient code through the strategic use of a variable?  Having a variable does not make inefficient code, but not having variables might.

Comment: I really wonder what's the problem with a variable, it makes the code efficient and readable. Go for it!

Comment: As @Amy said, your fear of "performance issues using variables" is, in fact, causing you performance issues.  Variables don't degrade performance per-se, but what you do with them *does*.  Your "one liner" is probably hiding a whole bunch of temporary variables that you can't *see*.  Just because they're not there in the code, doesn't mean they don't exist during execution.  At the end of the day, there are inputs and there are outputs.  Assigning outputs and re-using them is far more performant.

Comment: All a variable really does is store the result of an (expensive) operation so it doesn't need to be repeated.  Really all that happens is a few bytes are set aside in memory to store the reference until it goes out of scope.  That's it.  This doesn't introduce inefficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a "replace in place" function for strings in general, since they are immutable. The shortest method would be to capture the control in a variable and change its `text` property:

```
var x = checkout.Find("Summary").GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>();
x.text = x.text.Replace("$V", InventoryManager.money.ToString());
```

If you do this hundreds of times, you could create an extension method:

```
public static void ReplaceText(this Text component, string original, string replacement)
{
    component.text = component.text.Replace(original, replacement);
}
```

*then* you could do:

```
checkout.Find("Summary").GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>()
        .ReplaceText("$V", InventoryManager.money.ToString())
```

Now you don't have any variables!! /s